# jq compare two jsons and replace the value

Tags: json, jq, variadic-templates, template-engine

I have two JSON files

Filename `Abc.json`

```
{
  "name": "testfile",
  "version": "1.0",
  "dev": {
    "LoggingLevel": "DEBUG",
    "logging.level.HikariPool": "DEBUG",
    "spring.testname": "@@CONSENT_RW@@",
    "spring.testpassword": "@@CONSETNPWD@@"
  }
}
```

Filename `xyz.json`

```
{
  "name": "testset",
  "version": "1.0",
  "dev": {
    "@@CONSENT_RW@@": "ARM",
    "@@CONSETNPWD@@": "ARMPWD"
  }
}
```

So if a "dev" value in `abc.json` matches a "dev" key in `xyz.json` then I need to replace the value in `abc.json` by the corresponding value in `xyz.json`.

Comment: Please clarify what the matching criterion is supposed to be. Which "key" is xyz.json are you referring to?  Also, since SO is not a free programming service, it would probably be a good idea to show at least one of the jq programs you've tried.  That might also help us better understand the requirements.

Comment: @peak, I think it's unambiguous which keys the OP talks about - the variable parts are in the `"dev"` only, so apparently, the labels there in `xyz.json` have to be matched for values in the `"dev"` of `Abc.json` and replaced in the latter. To see a solution, you may run this: `<Abc.json jtc -w'<dev>l:>V<a:' -u xyz.json -u'<V>t'`

Comment: Hi the matching critieria here is @@CONSENT_RW@@ and @@CONSETNPWD@@ on both the json files

Comment: @MADHURAGHAV, in general it helps if you also show the desired output (quite often it's not obvious and sometimes does not follow from the query).

Comment: So the desired out of Abc.json should be

{
  "name": "testfile",
  "version": "1.0",
  "dev": {
    "LoggingLevel": "DEBUG",
    "logging.level.HikariPool": "DEBUG",
    "spring.testname": "ARM",
    "spring.testpassword": "ARMPWD"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
< abc.json jq --argfile vars xyz.json '
  $vars.dev as $dict
  | .dev |= map_values( $dict[.] // .)'
```

If you're squeamish about using --argfile, you could (for example) use --slurpfile instead, though in that case `$vars.dev` would be replaced by `$vars[0].dev`